# Run plsql procedure from concurrent on Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create a stored procedure that send parameter input into table. When I tried to compile my store procedure from SQL Developer it was running well,but i want to run this procedure from Concurrent in Oracle EBS 12.

However, this is the Error Message :

> Cause: FDPSTP failed due to ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'RUN_THIS_THING' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   .

And this is my code :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  RUN_THIS_THING
(errbuf  out varchar2,retcode out varchar2, P_RUN_FROM IN NUMBER, P_RUN_TO IN NUMBER, P_USER IN VARCHAR2) IS

BEGIN 
declare cursor c_header is
    select
        aia.party_id,
        aia.INVOICE_ID,
        aia.INVOICE_NUM,
        AIA.VENDOR_ID,
        AIA.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE,
        aia.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
        aia.DESCRIPTION,  
        aia.INVOICE_DATE,
        aia.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE,
        AIA.GL_DATE,
        AIA.DOC_SEQUENCE_VALUE
        from
        AP.ap_invoices_all aiA
    where
         AIA.DOC_SEQUENCE_VALUE BETWEEN P_RUN_FROM  AND  P_RUN_TO;
    h_rec c_header%rowtype;

begin 
    open c_header;
    loop
    fetch c_header into h_rec;
    exit when c_header%notfound;
    BEGIN
        insert into RUN_TEMP
        (
        INVOICE_ID               ,
        LAST_UPDATE_DATE         ,
        LAST_UPDATED_BY          ,
        VENDOR_ID                ,
        PARTY_ID                 ,
        INVOICE_NUM              ,
        TTDV_NUM                 ,
        CURRENCY                 ,
        INVOICE_AMOUNT           ,
        INVOICE_DATE             ,
        INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE    ,
        GL_DATE                  ,
        DESCRIPTION
        )
        values
        (
        h_rec.INVOICE_ID,
        sysdate,
        p_user,
        h_rec.VENDOR_ID,  
        h_rec.party_id,
        h_rec.INVOICE_NUM,
        h_rec.DOC_SEQUENCE_VALUE,
        h_rec.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE,
        h_rec.INVOICE_AMOUNT,
        h_rec.INVOICE_DATE,
        h_rec.INVOICE_RECEIVED_DATE,
        h_rec.GL_DATE  ,
        h_rec.DESCRIPTION         
        );
        END;
    end loop;
  close c_header;
commit;
end;
END;
```

It fails look like the procedure does not compile and I have already tried to grant my user execute rights to that package. It did not work. What else can I look at? What else could be causing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CREATE or REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM RUN_THIS_THING FOR RUN_THIS_THING;

Try this statement or change as needed. Synonym missing.